# Directory.GetFiles how to access subdirectories?

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I get files from sub-directories as well, using this code only gets the job done for files under the directory listed:

```
    DirectoryInfo selDir = new DirectoryInfo(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath + "\\Output");

foreach (FileInfo d in selDir.GetFiles())
    {
        //my code
    }
```

Comment: You'd have to be blind to make sense of this snippet, a directory you just created isn't going to have any files.

Comment: ooh i am really sorry, the code was incomplete, lemme edit that.Done.

Comment: -1: you can't have even read the documentation for the method you're already calling if you've not found how to include subdirectories: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var allFiles = selDir.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: Thank you sir, works like charm.

Answer (score 2):

You have the DirectoryInfo of your desired folder, so loop over all it's directories, then you can get the files for each.

```
DirectoryInfo selDir = new DirectoryInfo(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "Output"));

foreach (string dir in System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(selDir.FullName, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(dir))
    {
        //my code
    }
}
```

Comment: Wont work, since dir is a "GetDirectories" and not a "GetFiles", but thanks

Answer (score 2):

I usually make a recurring method to do this. Example:

```
    private void getFiles(string directory)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(directory);
        string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(directory);

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            // Code here.
        }

        foreach (string subDirectory in directories)
        {
            // Call the same method on each directory.
            getFiles(subDirectory);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not just use `SearchOption.AllDirectories` when you call `GetFiles`?

Answer (score 1):

```
DirectoryInfo selDir = new DirectoryInfo(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
Directory.CreateDirectory(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath + "\\Output");

string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(selDir.FullName, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (string file in files)
{
    // your code
}
```